# Using the stack with variable parameters as an exchange storage location?

Tags: c

Let's consider this unconventional piece of code:

```
inline void foo (int *p) {
    int n = *p;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
       // Here is just an dummy example. 
       int tmp = p[i];
       p[i] = p[i+1];
       p[i+1] = p[i];
    }
}

void bar (int p, ...) {
    foo (&p);
}
```

We were recently investigating a bug that showed after a compiler upgrade (ADI SHARC ADSP C/C++ Compiler) and I have found this ridiculous implementation where the address to the local variable `p` is passed to the function `foo`.

We have discovered that the only difference between the old and new compiler is that only the new compiler does effectively inline `foo`. When optimization is enabled `-o3` my dummy example vanishes from the output assembly. I am not very surprised because I am not effectively using `p`.

The purpose of this implementation is actually quite clever. We would like to pass some variable length data to `bar` using the `stack` as temporarily storage location. I guess that a more adequate implementation would have been to use the `heap` or a global buffer. Unfortunately in such embedded applications we aim to avoid dynamic allocation and minimize the memory footprint.

So, my question has two parts:

> 1. Is this implementation strictly acceptable?
> 2. What workaround can be used to prevent the compiler throwing away any piece >of code related to `p` (that only happens when `foo` is `inlined`)?

A potential successful hack would be this:

```
static volatile p_p;
void bar (int p, ...) {
    p_p = &p;
    foo (p_p);
}
```

#### Additional information from my compiler user's manual

Passing Parameters for Variable Argument Lists

```
int varying(char *fmt, int flag, ...) { /* ... */ }
```

To support this, the compiler passes the last named argument - flags, in this case - on the stack, even if it would normally have been passed in `R4`, `R8` or `R12` (in this case, it would have been passed in `R8`). Any following arguments after the last named argument are also passed on the stack.

Comment: @Quentin, dynamic allocation is very dangerous on an embedded platform because small architectures have no MMU and a very small amount of RAM. I have added some information to my question. The compiler is passing `p` and all the remaining arguments on the stack so `&p` is pointing to the start address of the buffer.

Comment: I did not know about `alloca()` thanks for teaching me. However this will not work because in this case `alloca()` need to be called before calling `bar`. Thus the `frame pointer` will not encompass the allocated space.

Comment: @Quentin This is interesting, I will look at it.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation is perfectly vaild for embedded systems. What you refer to is _heap_ based memory allocation with defragmentation, etc. But there are other ways like pools, etc. `alloca` is not standard. You might use VLAs instead - standard since C99 (which should be used anyway).

Comment: However, you might be better of with a struct-argument with a flexible array member.

Comment: @Quentin: `alloca` in the caller and pass by pointer as in your answer, for instance. The problem I see is OP uses array accesses to a variable argument list.If these are plain sequential, the `stdarg.h` way will work, too, however. But the number is limited and it is not possible to push them on the stack in a loop. Looks like an ugly hack to me either way.

Comment: @Quentin: OP seems to want to pass an array with length, so: `struct { size_t length; int data[]; }`

Comment: @Olaf Got it, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-standard, but defined way would be to use [`alloca()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) :

```
void bar() {
    int *storage = alloca(size * sizeof storage);
    foo(storage);
}
```

A standard way, but that needs C99 support, would be a [VLA](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) :

```
void bar() {
    int storage[size];
    foo(storage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use case for the `stdarg` set of macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void bar(int n, ...) {
    va_list args;
    int arg1, arg2;
    char *arg3;

    va_start(args, n);
    arg1 = va_arg(args, int);
    arg2 = va_arg(args, int);
    arg3 = va_arg(args, char *);
    printf("arg1=%d, arg2=%d, arg3=%s\n", arg1, arg2, arg3);
    va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    int a=1, b=2;
    char c[] = "hello";

    bar(3, a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=hello

You first call `va_start` to begin processing of the additional arguments, passing it the last known argument.  Then use `va_args` to return each argument, passing it the expected type.  Finish processing by calling `va_end`.

For more info: http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg

Comment: How would you rewrite this example in order to keep the call to `foo`?

Comment: @nowox I don't think you would need to.  If I understand correctly, the reason for keeping `foo` separate is to handle addressing of the additional arguments.  I'll add a more concrete example if that helps.

Comment: `foo` is needed because it is used by other functions not mentionned in my examples. These other functions have a more orthodox implementation where `*p` is pointing to a real storage location.

Comment: I think you're going to need to look up how to use stdarg.h. You can pass variable argument lists around, if necessary.